# idx_scan is very low in PostgreSQL statistic

Tags: postgresql, optimization, indexing

I would like to ask help in PostgresSQL optimization.

I have a medium sized table (about 2.000.000 records), and I wrote a very simple query like:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT(user_id)) 
FROM fp left outer join sd ON fp.session_id = sd.session_id 
WHERE fp.license_key = 'license'  AND sd.device_hash = 'hash'
```

I have simple indexes on 'license_key', 'user_id' and 'device_hash' (3 indexes)
The executor does not want to use my license_key index because there are more than 700.000 matches in the table and Seq Scan is better choice.

```
Aggregate  (cost=396247.61..396247.62 rows=1 width=17)

  ->  Hash Join  (cost=99668.54..396152.13 rows=38195 width=17)

        Hash Cond: ((fp.session_id)::text = (sd.session_id)::text)

        ->  Seq Scan on fp  (cost=0.00..293450.55 rows=706957 width=45)

              Filter: ((license_key)::text = 'license'::text)

        ->  Hash  (cost=98678.10..98678.10 rows=79235 width=28)

              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on sd  (cost=2902.50..98678.10 rows=79235 width=28)

                    Recheck Cond: ((device_hash)::text = 'hash'::text)

                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "sd.device_hash_btree_idx"  (cost=0.00..2882.69 rows=79235 width=0)

                          Index Cond: ((device_hash)::text = 'hash'::text)
```

I checked my statistics:

```
select * from where indexrelname= 'fp_license_key_btree_idx'

relid   |   indexrelname    |   idx_scan   |   idx_tup_read    |   idx_fetch
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
16430   |fp.license_key_btree_idx | 451    |    13641445       |    13641445
```

Can you give me advices ? How Can i improve my idx_scan? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with CTE and new index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON fp USING btree(session_id); --maybe cover license_key as well, but doubt it

WITH s AS (SELECT session_id FROM sd WHERE sd.device_hash = 'hash'),
     f AS (SELECT user_id, session_id
             FROM fp
            WHERE fp.license_key = 'license'
              AND session_id = ANY((SELECT array_agg(session_id) FROM s)::int[]))
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT(user_id)) 
FROM f
JOIN s ON f.session_id = s.session_id; --your left join is not left join anyway
```

Comment: Thank you, it became 4x faster. Can I have one more question? In cte s query uses bitmap heap scan before bitmap index scan, and it take 95% time of they query time, can I avoid it somehow?

Comment: You can't have one without the other, but you can disable that algorithm with `set enable_bitmapscan = 'off'` and see if it will do normal index scan and perform any better.